# How do I set up Microsoft Contracts static checking in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: design-by-contract, microsoft-contracts

I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2010b2, and wanted to re-evaluate some of my questions about the Microsoft contracts static checker.

I managed to re-use most of the code by using the `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` namespace for the code, but I am unsure of how to enable the static checker.  Do I need an additional plug-in?

I was under the impression that design-by-contract was supposed to "just work" in VS2010.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping it would 'just work', too. It doesn't. You still need to install [the bits](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970) to get the static checking.